# Jenkins CI service stopped working in Gitlab since recent Gitlab update

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, gitlab-8

I've been using Gitlab and Jenkins continuous integration for a while. When a developer pushed some code into Gitlab, Jenkins was notified and a build event was triggered. For this I had Jenkins CI service enabled in Gitlab, with a custom server deploy key, and Gitlab hook plugin installed in Jenkins side.

This is not working any longer, since a couple of days.
I am using GitLab Enterprise Edition 8.0.1-ee, and Gitlab Hook plugin 1.3.1 for Jenkins.

I see in Gitlab that they added a full CI feature (runners, web hooks...), does this mean the support for this Jenkins CI service is no longer active in Gitlab? Has anybody experienced the same problem since this new Gitlab version was released, and if so, is there any configuration that has to be added to work again?
Thank you

Comment: I managed to find an alternative solution, by using direct Web Hook in Gitlab project configuration, this is the Web hook URL that I added so that the builds can be triggered: https://myjenkins_server/jenkins/gitlab/build_now

Answer (score 2):

GitLab Enterprise Edition still supports Jenkins CI service. If after an upgrade it no longer works it is either due to a configuration change or a bug.

The CI feature built in to GitLab 8.x is not related to the Jenkins service. It is GitLab's own CI build tool. This does not mean GitLab no longer supports Jenkins, though.

If you continue to have issues with the Jenkins service, please open a support request since you have support through your Enterprise subscription.